# Shorter solution to append split output

Tags: python, list

I have a list that need to be split and appended to different lists.
`input_data` contains coordinates which are separated by a comma:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = [], [], [], []

for entry in input_data:
    a1, b1 = entry[0].split(",")
    a2, b2 = entry[1].split(",")     
    x1.append(a1)
    y1.append(b1)
    x2.append(a2)
    y2.append(b2)
```

I also tested the `_` variable as a temporary variable:

```
for entry in input_data:
   x1.append(_), y1.append(_) = entry[0].split(",")
   x2.append(_), y2.append(_) = entry[1].split(",")
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Please show a reasonable sample input. The result will depend heavily on the type of data you're using.

Comment: @Guimoute. The structure of the input data does not appear to allow that.

Comment: Code Golf belongs on our sister site [codegolf.se], not Stack Overflow. Per the help center -- Stack Overflow is only for **practical**, answerable questions; focusing on terseness over readability or maintainability is inherently impractical.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. This is arguably not golf, and off-topic for code review. Improving transformation of datastructures seems on the right side of the on-topic threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible option is to transform each entry into something a bit more manageable, and then transpose:

```
preprocessed = [(*entry[0].split(","), *entry[1].split(",")) for entry in input_data]
result = list(zip(*preprocessed))
```

For a sample list

```
input_data = [('a,b', 'c,d'), ('e,f', 'g,h'), ('i,j', 'k,l')]
```

this appears to produce the desired result:

```
[('a', 'e', 'i'), ('b', 'f', 'j'), ('c', 'g', 'k'), ('d', 'h', 'l')]
```